# Euro symbol is displayed as "?"

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am having issue in displaying the Euro symbol using `<fmt:formatNumber type="currency">` for below code.

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="$l_thresholdValue}" minFractionDigits="0" type="currency" var="thresholdValue"/>
```

This code in working fine in other jsp page. I tried all the possible ways like saving the file in `UTF-8` and including the encoding style `<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>` in jsp file.

Still euro symbol is displayed as "`?`"

Can anyone help me

Comment: Did you put the encoding meta in your html too?

Comment: no html files are used

Comment: What is the output mimetype, then?

Comment: using this line <%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>

Comment: So, you're outputting html. Then my question is: do you include also the corresponding meta-tag

Comment: can you please send me the syntax. so that i can try that

Comment: Just after the `head` tag, add: `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Comment: if i include above line, some functionality is missing where euro used to display.

Comment: What functionality? Is your JVM using UTF-8?

Comment: Now we are getting like value attribute can not be parsed into java.lang.Number: "5000 &euro;

Comment: I'm afraid your problem is more complex than initially stated. You should add more info to the question, as, for example, the expected result and all relevant code and data.

Comment: Now instead of question mark it is displaying as "EUR"

Answer (score 1):

Better to use this:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-15">
```

I Hope this will help you

Comment: This looks like an encoding problem, so +1 to Santhosh's answer.  Besides that, I don't know if your library will allow you to do so, but you can consider too using the html code ( &euro; )